# set manipulated string to a variable

Tags: linux, bash

If I run this:
`echo "After-u-math-how-however" | cut -f1,2 -d'-'`

I get `After-u`

I want to set the output to a variable. But when I try to do this:

`myVar=echo "After-u-math-how-however" | cut -f1,2 -d'-'`

It fails with:
`bash: After-u-math-how-however: command not found`

I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: `myVar=$(something)`

Comment: That said, I'd generally suggest preferring parameter expansions over command substitutions; `fork()`ing off a subshell and then invoking an external command in it is a lot of overhead, relatively speaking.

Comment: How would you preferably do this command?

Comment: Depends on usage (and performance-vs-readability tradeoffs). If there's guaranteed to be at least two dashes, `IFS=- read -r a b _; myVar="$a-$b"` is a lot more efficient than the `cut` approach, despite being wordier. One can also use a regex: `[[ $string =~ ^([^-]*-[^-]*)- ]] && myVar=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`, f/e, is another in-process approach.